# We need to output this as a static site to be hosted on the clients servers

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My Client is willing to follow an unusual approach and wants to control the back-end through WordPress internally but output it as an static one on the live server. I this possible? Well I think it is, can anyone suggest me how should  I do it or send me any link through which I can find this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would assume wordpress comes with caching, so the files are 'static'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [StaticPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/staticpress/) plugin can generate the static site to a different folder which could then be uploaded to the remote server.  Depending on what kind of access is available on the remote server, some sort of automatic sync should also be possible.

Comment: Hey Shawn thanks for your answer but what my client is willing to have is that he still wants to keep updating the site using WordPress but the live output would be static.

Would this plugin would work according to above mentioned requirements.

Comment: Your client would manage through WordPress and then rebuild the static files when they are ready to push the files to production.  Your question made it sound like the WordPress installation is on a different server than the static one.  If that is not the case, there are a multitude of plugins that will make static cache versions of the site for faster load time.  I've used https://wordpress.org/plugins/zencache/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-static-cache/ in the past.  For a list of others, look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=static.

Comment: What u get at first is right the client would like the WP site to be internally hosted than of the static one , but seriously speaking I don't have any clues that how would I do it. Any help or suggestion would be great.
Their parent company's new policies says that they can not use wp but they want to use wp in such a manner that it doesn't seems to be a wp site. How is it possible.

Would the first plugin that u share would help.

Comment: Static Press should work then.  They would simply need to do a rebuild whenever they are ready to push to the live site again and then copy the updated/new files over.

Comment: Thank you, I know most of the people were unable to answer to this question.

Last thing, lets say their domain name is www.jinglebell.com so would I have to make the wp version live on this domain with any extension from where the client would be able to access the wp and whenever they edit something they have to push it through the plugin so that the static version gets updated on the original domain which is www.jinglebell.com

Or if u could talk to me on Skype to explain this, that would be great too. BTW you are great.
This is my Skype:
Immad.hamid

Comment: Are you there Shawn?

Comment: Unless they are hard coding the domain into any links, everything should be exported as relative paths.  Therefore, no conversion should be required, a simple file transfer should do the trick.  I am on my way home right now, but maybe could skype later tonight if you still need help.

Comment: That would be great if u could Skype. I know your time is precious would not take much of your time.